# IOError: Errno 13 Permission Denied D:/PDFs when running python loop in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I'm running a loop in Windows Powershell that runs a script from pdfminer, pdf2txt.py on a directory of files. Here's the loop:

```
$PATH="D:/PDFdirectory"

foreach ($f in $PATH)
{   
python pdf2txt.py -o $f.txt "$f" "${f%.pdf}.txt"
}
```

I'm getting the permission denied error when I try to run the code above in Powershell. The error is pointing to outfp=file(outfile, 'w+b') in the pdf2txt script below.

```
if outfile:
    outfp = file(outfile, 'w+b')
else:
    outfp = sys.stdout
if outtype == 'text':
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, laparams=laparams,
                           imagewriter=imagewriter)
elif outtype == 'xml':
    device = XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, laparams=laparams,
                          imagewriter=imagewriter)
elif outtype == 'html':
    device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, scale=scale,
                           layoutmode=layoutmode, laparams=laparams,
                           imagewriter=imagewriter)
elif outtype == 'tag':
    device = TagExtractor(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec)
else:
    return usage()
for fname in args:
    fp = file(fname, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos,
                                  maxpages=maxpages, password=password,
                                  caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        page.rotate = (page.rotate+rotation) % 360
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
device.close()
outfp.close()
return

if __name__ == '__main__': sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

I have changed the read and write conditions in pdf2txt.py to binary to be compatible with Windows but now I'm stuck. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running Powershell as Administrator?

Comment: Yes I started it as administrator

Comment: Are you sure that `foreach ($f in $PATH)` does what you want?  It looks like it has exactly one entry - the directory name - and doesn't enumerate the files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you have incorrect syntax in the PowerShell script.

This bit:

```
"${f%.pdf}.txt"
```

Is asking to find a variable named `f%.pdf` and add ".txt" it its value to create a string.  You don't have a variable like that, so all you get is ".txt".

Your second problem (which I am guessing at) is that you seem to be wanting to iterate over all the PDF files in that directory.  But you haven't instructed PowerShell to do that.

So together, I think you want this code:

```
$PATH="D:/PDFdirectory"

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $PATH -Include *.pdf) {
    python pdf2txt.py -o "$($f.BaseName).txt" -O $f.DirectoryName ($f.FullName -replace '.pdf$','.txt')
}
```

More explanation:

- `$f.DirectoryName` - The path of the directory containing the file
- `$f.BaseName` - The name of the file without extension
- `"$($f.BaseName).txt"` - The parentheses mark off a sub expression that will be executed before constructing the final string.
- `($f.FullName -replace '.pdf$','.txt')` - Use a regex replace to find `.pdf` at the end of the full file name (and path) and replace it with `.txt`.

Comment: DirectoryName is pointing to where the files are going or where pdf2txt.py is?
and $f.BaseName == file ?

Comment: Where the PDF files are.